# angular Failed to instantiate module myModule issue

Tags: angularjs, karma-mocha

I am configuring my Karma amd mocha framework with grunt in my project.
When I am running `karma start` I am getting below mentioned error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModule' is not available!
```

My controller:

```
(function () {

    var module = angular.module('myModule',[]);

    module.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $q, $rootScope, templateValuesSrv) {
        function() {
          var self = this;

          self.firstName = '';
          self.lastName = '';

          self.getFullName = function() {
            return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName;
          };

          return self;
        }
    });
})();
```

My Controller Spec:

```
describe('myCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  describe('getFullName()', function() {
    it('should handle names correctly', inject(function($controller) {
      var myController = $controller('myCtrl');

      myController.firstName = 'George';
      myController.lastName = 'Harrison';

      myController.getFullName().should.equal('George Harrison');
    }));
  });
});
```

My Karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Nov 27 2015 11:48:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'test/specs/*.js',
      //'test/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Please suggest what I am missing.

Comment: You missed to initialize it, try `angular.module('myModule', [ ])`.

Comment: Please check it.. Edited my post..

Comment: Post your karma configuration. I think the problem is that you are missing the files where the module is defined

Comment: @Raulucco Added karma configuration code

Comment: Can you see what I am missing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the specs you should add the js files that you want to test.
// Karma conf

```
   files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'src/**/*.js',
      'test/specs/*.js',
      //'test/*.js'
    ],
```

If you use a bundler like webpackt or bower then you could require then on each spec